# Insert an identical value in a column for all the rows of a neighbouring column

Tags: mysql

I have a select statement which fetches 100 rows of data and inserts it in a table. However, I want to insert to insert `1` into the other column for all the rows I have inserted in the neighbouring column.

This is my insert select statement

```
insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id) 
VALUES (( 
          select cs_id 
          from class_students 
          where cs_class_id = 1 AND cs_year_id = 1 ),1);
```

On running the query, I get this **error**

> /* SQL Error (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row */

Comment: You can find answer to your quesiton here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select

Comment: First,when u try to insert into a table, remove the key word 'VALUES', Secondly, the number of columns which u want to insert does not match to the number of columns in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id)  
          select cs_id,1 
          from class_students 
where cs_class_id = 1 AND cs_year_id = 1;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72496/1)

Comment: I get this error `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: ed_examination_id might be a foreign key and you don't have data '1' in the related table. Please confirm

Comment: I do have 1 in a related table.

Comment: edit the question to show the create table out put for the two tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id)  (select cs_id,1 as "COLUMN_NAME" from class_students where cs_class_id = 1 AND cs_year_id = 1);
```