# Why SQL can't add and retrieve at one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

I want to select from a table its values and then at the same SQL statement I want to insert these values into another table

```
SELECT  `DVD_ID`, `dvd_gerne`, `dvd_Director`, `dvd_price`, `dvd_Title`, `photoName` 
FROM `DVDs_Details` WHERE DVD_ID='1' 
AND INSERT INTO `sta177_Rented` VALUES([DVD_ID-1], [dvd_gerne-2], [dvd_Director-3], [dvd_price-4], [dvd_Title-5], [photoName-6]')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is done with an [Insert-With-Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select)

```
INSERT INTO `sta177_Rented`  (`DVD_ID`, `dvd_gerne`, `dvd_Director`, `dvd_price`, `dvd_Title`, `photoName`)
    SELECT  `DVD_ID`, `dvd_gerne`, `dvd_Director`, `dvd_price`, `dvd_Title`, `photoName` 
    FROM `DVDs_Details` 
    WHERE DVD_ID='1'
```

Comment: Not quite, but nearly.

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify which columns you want to insert values into like this

```
INSERT INTO `sta177_Rented` (`DVD_ID`, `dvd_gerne`, `dvd_Director`, `dvd_price`, `dvd_Title`, `photoName`)
SELECT  `DVD_ID`, `dvd_gerne`, `dvd_Director`, `dvd_price`, `dvd_Title`, `photoName`
FROM `DVDs_Details` WHERE DVD_ID='1'
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to try something like below

```
Insert into sta177_Rented
SELECT  DVD_ID, dvd_gerne, dvd_Director, dvd_price, dvd_Title, photoName FROM 
DVDs_Details WHERE DVD_ID=1
```

Comment: @KayNelson Thanks for your comments, but here we are trying to help each other to resolve the issues, pin pointing the syntax and English is not the right approach I think.

Comment: Hi Rao. When you post the wrong syntax, im supposed to point it out. Otherwise we have wrong answers. If you change your answer to a correct syntax, i will upvote it.