# Mysql ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to insert some data with MySQL using a subquery like so:

```
INSERT
INTO dw_plynjasa.jumlah_fact
    SELECT null, jasa_sk, waktu_sk, sum(hrg_pes), count(d.no_pes) 
    FROM   dw_plynjasa.jasa_dim      a,
           dw_plynjasa.waktu_dim     b,
           oltp_plynjasa.detil_pesan c,
           oltp_plynjasa.pesan       d,
           oltp_plynjasa.jasa        e
    WHERE  b.tgl = d.tgl_pes
      AND  a.kd_jasa = e.kd_jasa
      AND  a.nm_jasa = e.nm_jasa
      AND  a.satuan = e.satuan
      AND  a.hrg_satuan = e.hrg_satuan 
    GROUP  BY (jasa_sk, waktu_sk);
```

but I get only `error 1241, operand should contain 1 column(s)`

How can I fix my query?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5391390/4350275

Comment: I've rewritten this post for clarity of English and also clarity in the formatting, which makes the errors easier to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group by` should be on individual columns and comma separated.
They should not be a grouped as a *set*.

Remove *parenthesis* `(` and `)` in `group by` clause.

**Example**:

```
mysql> select * from so.employee where 1=2 group by empno, deptno;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from so.employee where 1=2 group by (empno, deptno);
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
mysql>
```

**Change**:

```
GROUP BY (jasa_sk,waktu_sk);
```

**To**:

```
GROUP BY jasa_sk, waktu_sk;
```