# Insert multiple values to child table with primary id

Tags: mysql

TABLE ONE

```
a_id, a_title, a_desc, user_id
```

TABLE TWO

```
a_id, to_user_id
```

The script i have written so far puts all data in one table with 5 columns 
like this

```
a_id, a_title, a_desc, user_id, to_user_id
```

Code :

```
INSERT INTO table(a_title,a_desc,user_id,to_uid_fk)
VALUES('$title','$desc','$uid','$UserTo')
```

the script and the data are send ok

to_user_id stores multiples ids (e.g. 123,432,1232 and so on) thats why i created another child table to store to_user_id in different rows.

How do i do that?

1. how to i take the a_id which is auto increment and take it to the child (second) table
2. how do i store multiple values of to_user_id?

this is how i want to store data in the child table

```
INSERT INTO table_name (a_id,to_user_id)
VALUES ('3','634'), ('3','6532'), ('3','194');
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select

Comment: I should take the id with a select like this right?  INSERT INTO table_two (a_id,to_user_id) SELECT a_id
FROM table_one?

Comment: Can you post the full script?

Comment: A script that will store the a_id from the table_one and store the to_user_id variable which has multiple values?