# I am not able to get 1 value from a table to a different table

Tags: php, sql

I have some trouble trying to get column values from a table to a different table.

I got a table called sorting_orders and a table thats called new_tags and theres a column in sorting_orders thats called orders. Theres also a column in sorting_orders with IDS that match with the IDS from new_tags.

What i need is to get all the values from the column "orders" to a column in new_tags which is called "sorting" while the IDS are matching from both tables.

I tried various querys but usually i get a warning message that says several fields dont have a default value. After I got this warning my entire table went empty except the sorting column.

INSERT INTO new__tags(sorting) SELECT orders FROM sorting_orders the warning i get is Field X doesn't have a default value. after this it just sets it to null while it had a value before

Thank you very much, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please show the query you've tried.

Comment: @kerv then you are using the wrong place on the internet. please visit http://www.google.com and try again!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select

Comment: "I tried various querys but usually i get a warning message"   Show the query and the message.

Comment: INSERT INTO new__tags(sorting)
SELECT orders FROM sorting_orders

the warning i get is Field X doesn't have a default value. after this it just sets it to null while it had a value before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @low_rents Did you even read the question? I have difficulties with creating an SQL query. Not with any code....

Comment: @kerv well, I did - and you know for sure that you have to try coding yourself and paste what you have tried when asking a question here on SO. and the text used to write SQL queries is considered being **code**.

Comment: @low_rents Ok, I edited my question. Hopefully its more clear now.

Comment: @KiwiJuicer I have tried this but i get the warning  Field X doesn't have a default value, then it creates a new empty row with nothing in it and the intended row stayed the same.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: @KiwiJuicer INSERT INTO new__tags (sorting)
SELECT `orders`
FROM   sorting_orders
WHERE  id = 458;

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an update by select.

Use this as example:

```
UPDATE new__tags nt, (SELECT orders FROM sorting_orders so where so.id = 458) src 
  SET nt.sorting = src.orders where nt.id = 458 ;
```