# SQL - Insertion of row with selection from other row IF the row doesn't exits

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

So, I'm wanting to insert a row into the table `teams_views` IF the row doesn't already exist. This is a simple query, but I'm having issues including a selection into this query. Basically, one of the fields in the row is in need of being fetched from another table.

Here's a breakdown of what I am wanting to build in SQL:

```
INSERT INTO
    teams_views (col1, col2)
VALUES
    (SELECT col1 FROM teams WHERE teams.identifier = 1234, col2)
WHERE
    teams_views.col1
IS NULL
```

What can I do to get this query work?
Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5391390/1666800

Comment: Is `col1` a unique key in the table? You can use `INSERT IGNORE` to prevent adding a row if it already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO teams_views (col1, col2)
SELECT t.col1 ,  t.col2
FROM teams t
WHERE t.identifier = 1234
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM teams_views
                WHERE t.col1 = col1)
```