# How can I do in MySQL an Insert with Select only if there is a value in the selected column?

Tags: mysql

I'm using *MySQL* and I have this kind of table:

```
table: historic_v1
id | student_id | level1_start_date | level1_score | level2_start_date | level2_score
1  | 2345       | 2016-02-10        | 7.5          | 2016-04-15        | 5
2  | 5634       | 2016-03-05        | NULL         | NULL              | NULL
3  | 4885       | 2015-12-02        | 6            | 2016-01-05        | NULL
```

I want to do an *Insert* in table *historic_v2* with a *Select* in *historic_v1*, but I only want to have a row in *historic_v2* if the value of the selected field in *historic_v1* is not *NULL*.

I mean, the *historic_v2* table needs to be like this:

```
table: historic_v2
id | student_id | level | key        | date       | score
1  | 2345       | 1     | start date | 2016-02-10 | NULL
2  | 2345       | 1     | score      | NULL       | 7.5
3  | 2345       | 2     | start date | 2016-04-15 | NULL
4  | 2345       | 2     | score      | NULL       | 5
5  | 5634       | 1     | start date | 2016-03-05 | NULL
6  | 4885       | 1     | start_date | 2015-12-02 | NULL
7  | 4885       | 1     | score      | NULL       | 6
8  | 4885       | 2     | start_date | 2016-01-05 | NULL
```

In this example, the student *2345* will have 4 rows in the *historic_v2* table, the student *5634* only 1 row and the student *4885* 3 rows.

How can I do this *Insert* with *Select*?

**P.S.:** I know that this structure is not nice, but it's just a small example of what I really need to do, and the solution of this problem will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try to use an event or trigger

Comment: you want insert  (more or less) a row in historic_v2  for each column in historic_v1 ?

Comment: What is the logic behind how many rows have each student? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I don't get how difficult to understand is my question for you. In my second paragraph I said that I want to insert into _historic\_v2_ not _NULL_ fields from _historic\_v1_, so the logic behind "how many rows have each student" is the number of not _NULL_ fields in _historic\_v1_ table the user has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a select union

```
insert into historic_v2 (student_id, level, key , date , score)
select student_id, 1, 'start date', level1_start_date, null
from historic_v2
where level1_start_date is not null 
union 
select student_id, 1, 'score', null, level1_score
from historic_v2
where level1_score is not null 
union 
select student_id, 2, 'start date', level2_start_date, null
from historic_v2
where level2_start_date is not null 
union 
select student_id, 2, 'score', null, level2_score
from historic_v2
where level2_score is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar thread: [INSERT with SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select)

You can work off something like this..

```
INSERT INTO historic_v2 (...)
SELECT ...
FROM historic_v1
WHERE ...
```