# MySQL: How to insert values from one table into another using with a correlated subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm new to MySQL and am trying to do the following:

I have a table 'links' that with a new column called 'project_id", and an existing column called 'project'. I have a second table called 'projects', with a column called 'id'.

I need to use the value of 'links > project' to loop over the corresponding id 'projects > id', and then insert it into 'links > project_id'. Once that is done, we will no longer need 'links > project', as 'links > project_id' will become a foreign key and we can then simply look it up in 'projects'.

My pseudo sql code (I'm brand new to this) looks like:

```
INSERT INTO links(project_id)
select id 
from projects
where project = links(project_id)
```

Thanks (apologies in advance for being a newb)

Comment: Do you want the new project_id column to be a new record all on its own, or do you want to fill in the column on existing records?

Comment: The new links(project_id) column is net new for existing rows. The values from project(id) needs to fill links(project_id) based on the the value of links(project).

Comment: So the project Id is already in the links table under project? Otherwise, what is the content of the project column?

Comment: The project id (int) is newly created in the links table. There is a project (varchar) column in links we want to no longer use that has the project name. Since we now have a projects table (with id, project), we want to read each row of links, get links(project), pass that value into a subquery, to then get the value of projects(id) where projects(project) = links(project), and INSERT that value back up to links(project_id). That way, we can kill off links(project) VARCHAR and only have links(project_id).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but assumes that each `project.project` value exactly matches the `links.project` field.

```
UPDATE links AS l
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Id, project FROM project
    ) AS a ON a.project = l.project
SET l.project_id = p.Id
```

This will update the `project_id` field on the `links` table with the corresponding `id` from the `projects` table that matches the value in `links.project`.

If you want to create a new record, use the following

```
INSERT INTO links (project_id)
SELECT Id FROM project p 
INNER JOIN links l ON l.project = p.project
```

In both cases, the `INNER JOIN` will make sure that only records from `project` that already have an equivalent record in `links` will be used for this operation.

Comment: Yes, the projects.project column was populated with the distinct values from links.project.

Comment: No worries, hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, absolutely, but check the syntax :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

[INSERT with SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select)