# I need to do a insert in a specific row after a select with inner join to know which row

Tags: mysql

I did

```sql
SELECT F.id
FROM ftable F 
  INNER JOIN dtable D ON (F.id= D.id) 
WHERE D.email = 'abc@abc.com';
```

now I need to do a insert in a ftable column using the select result as the where indicator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT with SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select)

Comment: `INSERT INTO f VALUES(x,y,z) WHERE f.id IN (<your select statement goes here>);` should do the trick.

Comment: Plz be little clear, not getting wht u r trying to do

Comment: @JNevill got 'where is not valid input at this position'

Comment: @Rams I need to do a insert in a specific ftable row. To know that row, I did a select (query above), but I don't know how to do the select and the insert in the same query

Answer (score 0):

You can simply insert those selected values by putting insert into before ur select.

```
Insert into ftable
    SELECT F.* FROM ftable F 
                INNER JOIN dtable D ON (F.id= D.id) 
                WHERE D.email = 'abc@abc.com';
```