# How to copy multiple row from a table and insert those to another table in MySql DB with PHP?

Tags: mysql

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('hostname','username','passwd','dbname');
    $query = 'SELECT name,mobileno FROM test';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $monileno = $row['mobileno'];

        $query2 = "INSERT INTO test2(name2,mobileno2) VALUES('$name','$monileno')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
       }
?>


CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` INT(9) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `mobileno` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `name`, `mobileno`) VALUES
(1, 'Omar Faruq', '01911775477'),
(2, 'omar Al Faruq', '01911775477'),
(3, 'Helal Uddin', '01914351075');

CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` INT(9) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `mobileno` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This code works on Xampp/wamp but when I upload this script to RHEL7.2 web server it does not works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT with SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('hostname','username','passwd','dbname');
$query = 'SELECT name,mobileno FROM test';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  $name = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['name']);
  $monileno = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['mobileno']); 

$query2 = "INSERT INTO test2(name2,mobileno2) VALUES('$name','$monileno')";
mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
?>
```

and change on Database :

CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` INT(9) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name2` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobileno2` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Finally it works on RHEL7.  I am really happy...... Thanks All

Answer (score -2):

try replacing

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
```

with

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // OR
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

It seem's like you we're mixing between the object-oriented usage style and the procedural style.

I'm surprised this worked for you. probably might be due to different php versions.

same thing can apply to

```
VALUES('$name','$monileno')";
//replace with
VALUES('" . mysqli_escape_string($conn, $name) . "', '" . mysqli_escape_string($conn, $monileno) . "')";
```

Comment: That code is still highly vulnerable. What if the name is given as `Little ' Bobby Tables`?

Comment: I noted it above the code. Though I was trying to find why his code is not working and not pentest it.

Comment: I also treated special strings like @Nico noted. Let's see what op says

Comment: `myqsli_escape_string` has a typo in it, and the method `mysqli_escape_string` needs two arguments.....

Comment: Edited, sorry I typed from my phone :)