# MySQL - select or insert

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have users from many external sources which I try to map to internal userId, so the table I have is:

```
userId, externalSourceId, externalUserId
```

In my code, I'm getting `externalSourceId` and `externalUserId` and want to get the `userId` from the database, if exists, otherwise, create one and return the newly created value. I need this action to be atomic because several processes may try to do the same thing at the same time, so I wished only the first time will create a `userId`.

In pseudo code it will look like that:

1. u = find user with (externalSourceId, externalUserId)
2. if no u:
   2.1. u = create new user with (externalSourceId, externalUserId) and random userId
3. return u

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/5391390/3461055

Comment: @ArifKhan - No because it doesn't select the value if it already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `users`
(`externalSourceId`, externalUserId)
VALUES( 10, 100)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE userId=userId
```

You can also use `insert ignore`. You can read more about [DUPLICATE KEY versus INSERT IGNORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: The thing is that on "duplicate" I want to return the original userId, not update it.

Comment: This would be the same `userId` that already exists. So yes, there would be one db update request.

Comment: But I still not "getting" it outside. I can do it with two SQL queries. But I'm going to have many "gets" and few "creates" so it seems a big overhead.

Comment: AFAIK, if you are using raw queries, result of `insert` itself is boolean and does not return the inserted object. If you are using ORM, I would look if that ORM supports this. For example, Sequelize supports [findOrCreate](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#-findorcreate-search-for-a-specific-element-or-create-it-if-not-available)

Answer (score 1):

INSERT IGNORE INTO test (`externalSourceId`,`externalUserId`) VALUES (23,32);

SELECT `userId` FROM test WHERE `externalSourceId`=23 AND `externalUserId`=32;

You can use this if externalSourceId and externalUserId are defined unique.