# My php form is only saving the last row of my table.

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table within a form (new_tear.php) that takes data from a single user. The first cloumn is populated from a database table (ProfileTable) with names.
The user has to select an option from a dropdown for each row (each name).
When the form is submitted (POST to tear_done.php), I want to store each row in my database.
However, I am only seeing the last row posted each time

new_ter.php

```
<?php
$sqlT1 = "SELECT * FROM ProfileTable WHERE dept = 'T1'";
$queryT1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlT1);
if (!$queryT1) {
  die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
<form action="tear_done.php" method="post">
<table>
<?php
    $no     = 1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryT1))
    {
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$no.'</td>
                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                <td><select id="Dz_M" name="Dz_M">
                    <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
                    <option value="8am">8am</option>
                    <option value="Rest">Rest</option>
                </select><br>
                </td>
                <td><select id="Dz_T" name="Dz_T">
                    <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
                    <option value="8am">8am</option>
                    <option value="Rest">Rest</option>
                </select><br>
                </td>
                <td><select id="Dz_W" name="Dz_W">
                    <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
                    <option value="8am">8am</option>
                    <option value="Rest">Rest</option>
                </select><br>
                </td>
                <td><select id="Dz_F" name="Dz_F">
                    <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
                    <option value="8am">8am</option>
                    <option value="Rest">Rest</option>
                </select><br>
                </td>
                <td><select id="Dz_S" name="Dz_S">
                    <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
                    <option value="8am">8am</option>
                    <option value="Rest">Rest</option>
                </select><br>
                </td>                   
                </tr>';
        $no++;
        $no_cont = $no;
    }?> 
</table>
<br>
<button value="save" type="submit" name="save">Save Tear</button>       
</form>
```

tear_done.php

```
<?php
$sqlT1 = "SELECT * FROM ProfileTable WHERE dept = 'T1'";
$queryT1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlT1);
if (!$queryT1) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
$no = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryT1))
{
$Name = $row ['name'];
$Dept = $row ['dept'];
$DZ_M = $_POST ["Dz_M"];
$DZ_T = $_POST ["Dz_T"];
$DZ_W = $_POST ["Dz_W"];
$DZ_F = $_POST ["Dz_F"];
$DZ_S = $_POST ["Dz_S"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO TearTable (name, Mdy, Tdy, Wdy, Fdy, Sdy, dept)
VALUES ('$Name', '$DZ_M', '$DZ_T', '$DZ_W', '$DZ_F', '$DZ_S', '$Dept')";    

echo $no;
echo '<br>';
echo $sql; //for testing
echo '<br>';
$no++;
}   
?>
```

What I am getting from the echo is the sql with all the names and dept correct, however the other fields $DZ_M, $DZ_T etc only repeat the last row entered from the table in new_tear.php. 
What is it am I missing please?

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something, the code you've shared defines a variable with `INSERT INTO` code but never executes it.

Comment: Could not see the sql code that does the insert. How are you getting last row inserted

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: Alvaro Gonzalez and Indra Kumar, Firstly, thanks for the reply. I edited my code to make it shorter, I'm sorry for the confusion. I removed the execution for testing purposes. The line 'echo $sql' is just for testing if its being written properly.

Comment: Tadman,Thanks for the reply, Its for an internal network, never going online outside.

Comment: I would not use iterated INSERT queries.  I'd use [INSERT with SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5391344/2943403).

Answer (score 0):

Inside While loop Just concat the insert query strings

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryT1))
{
......

$sql .= "INSERT INTO TearTable (name, Mdy, Tdy, Wdy, Fdy, Sdy, dept)
VALUES ('$Name', '$DZ_M', '$DZ_T', '$DZ_W', '$DZ_F', '$DZ_S', '$Dept');";    // Note .= and semicolon at the end 

   .....
    } 
// Outside the loop
execute your query here..
```

You should use prepared statements for security reasons

Comment: Don't use multi-query. You need to ensure those `INSERT` statements run correctly, and that requires firing them off individually and checking for errors. This just makes an awful mess of things.

Comment: @tadman Yes you are right. Individual queries will help us know whats happening with each insert. Since the OP asked "why only last one gets executed" i posted the above answer

Comment: @Indra Kumar, when I execute my query outside of the loop, only the last row of my table is shown. When I execute it within the loop, all the rows are shown, however, only data from the last row in the table is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by adding a var ($no) to the new_tear.php select id and name.

new_tear.php

```
<?php
    $no     = 1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryT1))
    {
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$no.'</td>
                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                <td><select id="Dz_M'  . $no . '" name="Dz_M'  . $no . '">
                    <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
                    <option value="8am">8am</option>
                    <option value="Rest">Rest</option>
                </select><br>
                </td>
                <td><select id="Dz_T'  . $no . '" name="Dz_T'  . $no . '">
                    <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
                    <option value="8am">8am</option>
                    <option value="Rest">Rest</option>
                </select><br>
                </td>
                <td><select id="Dz_W'  . $no . '" name="Dz_W'  . $no . '">
                    <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
                    <option value="8am">8am</option>
                    <option value="Rest">Rest</option>
                </select><br>
                </td>
                <td><select id="Dz_F'  . $no . '" name="Dz_F'  . $no . '">
                    <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
                    <option value="8am">8am</option>
                    <option value="Rest">Rest</option>
                </select><br>

                </td>
                <td><select id="Dz_S'  . $no . '" name="Dz_S'  . $no . '">
                    <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
                    <option value="8am">8am</option>
                    <option value="Rest">Rest</option>
                </select><br>
                </td>                   
                </tr>';
        $no++;
        $no_cont = $no;
    }?>
```

And adding the var ($no) to the $_POST in tear_done.php

tear_done.php

```
$Name = $row ['name'];
$Dept = $row ['dept'];
$DZ_M = $_POST ['Dz_M'.$no]; 
$DZ_T = $_POST ['Dz_T'.$no];
$DZ_W = $_POST ['Dz_W'.$no];
$DZ_F = $_POST ['Dz_F'.$no];
$DZ_S = $_POST ['Dz_S'.$no];
```

This solved my problem and now in the echo (again, only for testing) I see the sql looks correct. 
Thanks Much for your help everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Best would be to create one single big query statement.

```
$sql .= "INSERT INTO TearTable (name, Mdy, Tdy, Wdy, Fdy, Sdy, dept) VALUES"
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryT1)) {  
  $Name = $row ['name'];
  $Dept = $row ['dept'];
  $DZ_M = $_POST ["Dz_M"];
  $DZ_T = $_POST ["Dz_T"];
  $DZ_W = $_POST ["Dz_W"];
  $DZ_F = $_POST ["Dz_F"];
  $DZ_S = $_POST ["Dz_S"]; 
  $sql .= "('$Name', '$DZ_M', '$DZ_T', '$DZ_W', '$DZ_F', '$DZ_S', '$Dept'),"
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); //run your INSERT query.
```

This single query inserts all that data to the DB. 
The issue with this way of doing it is that it becomes harder to debug if your INSERT fails.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that but the result is the same. Could you clarify a bit please. Thank You.