# running two queries in php

Tags: php, html

I need help trying to make the below php code work. The code searches for User on the `Users` table. When doing the search I would like to insert the timestamp of the search in another table called `scan`. The purpose of this is to create a report with the table scan as I want to see every time a User has been searched.

However, everything works except for the second query. Can anyone help me identify what's wrong with the php code below and how can I make it work? Again, I would like to make the second query (INSERT INTO) work and to insert the searched data into the `scan` table.

```
 <?php
    // initalize the variables 
    $osha      = "";
    $firstname = "";
    $lastname  = "";
    $company   = "";
    $trade     = "";

    // php code to search data in mysql database and set it in input text
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        // connect to mysql
        $dbc = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "root","demodb");

        // id to search
        $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['user_id']);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_id = '$user_id' LIMIT 1";
        $rs    = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) == 1)
        {
          $row       = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
          $osha      = $row['osha'];
          $firstname = $row['firstname'];
          $lastname  = $row['lastname'];
          $company   = $row['company'];
          $trade     = $row['trade'];

          $query     = "INSERT INTO scan (user_id, osha, firstname, lastname, company, trade, email, picture) VALUES (" .
            "'" . $user_id . "', '" .
            "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $osha     ) . "', '" .
            "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $firstname) . "', '" .
            "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $lastname ) . "', '" .
            "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $company  ) . "', '" .
            "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $trade    ) . "')";
          mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        }
        else
        {
          echo "Undefined ID";
        }
    }    
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

        <head>

            <title> PHP FIND DATA </title>

            <meta charset="UTF-8">

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        </head>

        <body>

        <form action="barcode.php" method="post">

        Id:<input type="text" name="user_id"><br><br>

        Osha #:<input type="text" name="osha" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($osha) ?>"><br><br>

            First Name:<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($firstname) ?>"><br>
    <br>

            Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($lastname) ?>"><br><br>

        Company:<input type="text" name="company" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($company) ?>"><br><br>

        Trade:<input type="text" name="trade" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($trade) ?>"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">

               </form>

        </body>

    </html>
```

ADDING Tables definitions

`Users` Table

```
| Users | CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `osha` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=98819 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

`scan` Table

```
| scan  | CREATE TABLE `scan` (
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `osha` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, if all you're doing is *search and insert if found*, then you can do this in a single insert statement. See here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/5391344/296555. Ex. `INSERT INTO scan (user_id, ...) SELECT user_id... FROM Users WHERE user_id = :userId`. In addition, you're very open to SQL injection attacks. Look up parameterized queries. Parameterized queries will also help you avoid those unnecessary quotes which make it very difficult to debug. Here's a decent reference for PDO - https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: See @Alexandr Khomutetsky's answer. You are trying to insert into a table with 8 columns but only passing in 6 values. There might be other issues too. Please use error reporting to find out these types of issues - https://stackoverflow.com/q/22662488/296555

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting less data than you declare fields to insert. There are no values for fields 'email' and 'picture'. At least this could be reason of your problem.

Comment: I did try this. However, it seems that it was a combination of both having too many quotes and inserting less data. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your query results to a 2 single quote on the value.

Try this one.

```
$query     = "INSERT INTO scan (user_id, osha, firstname, lastname, company, trade, email, picture) VALUES (" .
        "'" . $user_id . "', " .
        "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $osha     ) . "', " .
        "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $firstname) . "', " .
        "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $lastname ) . "', " .
        "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $company  ) . "', " .
        "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $trade    ) . "')";
      mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

I would also suggest to using mysql parameter for good practices

Answer (score 0):

Untested but in looking at this you have a lot of extra, unneeded quotes at the end of each mysqli_real_escape_string line:

```
 <?php
    // initalize the variables 
    $osha      = "";
    $firstname = "";
    $lastname  = "";
    $company   = "";
    $trade     = "";

    // php code to search data in mysql database and set it in input text
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        // connect to mysql
        $dbc = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "root","demodb");

        // id to search
        $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['user_id']);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_id = '$user_id' LIMIT 1";
        $rs    = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) == 1)
        {
          $row       = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
          $osha      = $row['osha'];
          $firstname = $row['firstname'];
          $lastname  = $row['lastname'];
          $company   = $row['company'];
          $trade     = $row['trade'];

          $query     = "INSERT INTO scan (user_id, osha, firstname, lastname, company, trade, email, picture) VALUES (" .
            "'" . $user_id . "'," .
            "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $osha     ) . "', " .
            "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $firstname) . "', " .
            "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $lastname ) . "', " .
            "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $company  ) . "', " .
            "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $trade    ) . "')";
          mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        }
        else
        {
          echo "Undefined ID";
        }
    }    
    ?>
```