# Mysql insert with set and select

Tags: mysql, mysql-insert-id, mysql-select-db

I want to copy all records of one condition to new entries with other condition. in this example. i want to get all information of xxx=987 and add them with xxx=123 to the same table. So i want to copy some values, but not all into the new record.

```
INSERT table 
SET 
  pid = UPPER(UUID()),
  xxx = 123,
  (col1, col2) = (SELECT val1, val2 
                  FROM table
                  WHERE xxx = 987)
```

I tried many things, but it did not workout. any help highly appreciated
Best endo

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select

Comment: thanks, but i try to achieve this with an insert set statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) query :

```
INSERT INTO table (pid, xxx, val1, val2)
SELECT UPPER(UUID()), 123, val1, val2
FROM table
WHERE xxx = 987;
```

Comment: but with this solution i need to provide all fields of the table, i want to submit only specific fields, the not mentioned fields will then be filled with default values of table

Comment: it works, but i'd rather prefere to use INSERT with SET, since it is a bit more readable, if no better answer comes up, i think i go with your solution

Comment: @endoanaconda ... SET is for UPDATE queries, not for INSERTs.

Comment: AFAIK: INSERT with SET is equivalent to INSERT INTO with VALUES, and accoring to the documentation allowed: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: @endo.anaconda Yes, Insert works with set , but you can't use "select" with that combination, you can do: INSERT INTO table SET xxx='yyy' , but you cant do: INSERT INTO table SET xxx='yyy' , col2 = (SELECT zzz FROM ......)