# MySql Insert set with left join

Tags: mysql, sql

1)I want to insert Brand ID into Item table by using LEFT JOIN, below is the example code I tried to do , is it correct?

2)How to use INSERT SET with LEFT JOIN as I will get error message like this

> select is not valid at this position, expecting EOF

```
INSERT INTO Brand 
SET Name="BMW" 
SELECT b.ID
FROM Brand b
LEFT JOIN Item i ON i.BrandID = b.ID
```

**Brand**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | YSL |
| 2 | Gucci |
| 3 | Prada |

**Item**

| ID | BrandID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 3 | Luxury bag |
| 21 | 2 | Earing |

**Expected Result**
(The Brand ID is auto increment so I no need to insert it, and I know the item name being null is weird but I can't insert two table in one query.)

**Brand**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | YSL |
| 2 | Gucci |
| 3 | Prada |
| 4 | BMW |

**Item**

| ID | BrandID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 3 | Luxury bag |
| 21 | 2 | Earing |
| 22 | 4 | null |

Comment: Is the specified table data from _before_ your INSERT? Can you also specify the expected table data _after_ your INSERT.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? It seems you cannot use set and select within an insert in MySQL [Mysql insert with set and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037336/mysql-insert-with-set-and-select)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to `INSERT` the `Brand`s the `ID`s of which are not yet in the table `Brand`.

If the above is correct, then you can simply state which value to `INSERT` for the columns, like this:

```
INSERT INTO Brand (ID, Name)
SELECT DISTINCT i.BrandID, "BMW"
FROM Item i 
LEFT JOIN Brand b ON i.BrandID = b.ID
WHERE b.ID IS NULL /* This is to prevent duplicates on Brand.ID */
```

Comment: I want to insert Brand first and then insert the BrandID into Item table, so if I select i.ID like your answer then the Brand ID of BMW will be "22".

Comment: @Anno123 Then there was a mistake in your query, because you were joining on `i.ID` instead of `i.BrandID`. I updated my answer too. It's not an `INSERT SET`, but it still fulfills your requirement.