# How to insert a row of data into table A based on multiple other tables?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to insert a row of data into table A which contains the columns: School, Name, Colour, Age. Using the where clause I will need to get this information from the following tables: School_table, Name_table, Colour_table and Age_table.

```
INSERT INTO A (School, Name, Colour, Age)
// how do I add the values from the other tables into their respective columns?
```

Comment: If you can write a SELECT statement to fetch the data, then use `INSERT... SELECT` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select

Comment: That is a standard thing you will have to learn from SQL, there are probably many tutorials out there on how to use SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Use `INSERT... SELECT`. You can find the docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-insert.html)

A small sample to get you started:

```
INSERT INTO A (School, Name, Colour, Age) SELECT value_from_school_table, value_from_name_table, ... FROM school_table JOIN name_table ON ... WHERE field = value
```

First start with writing a query that fetches all the values you want to insert. Then just append that select statement to your insert.