# Insert row count result into another table

Tags: mysql

How can I count total rows from different tables and insert them into a column of a result table. In MySQL

```
Insert into hospitals(total_case)
Select count(*)
Id, count (id)
From Islamabad
```

Comment: here you're fetching 2 column but trying to insert in single column. That would be an issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INSERT with SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select)

Answer (score 0):

Number of columns in `INSERT INTO` statement should match with number of columns selected in `SELECT` clause.

You have selected two columns `count(*) Id, count (id)` but want to insert in single column `total_case` which would create an error.

```
INSERT INTO hospitals (total_case)
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM Islamabad;
```