# How to merge two tables together with same number of rows corresponding to same id numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL: How to merge two tables together with same number of rows corresponding to same id numbers? Can someone please help me with writing a query for this. I wrote this:

```
INSERT INTO table1.code
SELECT code FROM table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

But, I am getting mysql error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'table1.id' in 'where clause'`

Table 1

| id | name | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |  |
| 2 | def |  |
| 3 | ghi |  |

Table 2

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | Ab |
| 3 | D2 |

Required MYSQL DB Table 1

| id | name | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 12 |
| 2 | def | Ab |
| 3 | ghi | D2 |

Comment: insert into from select - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you simply need to join your two tables and update `table1`

```
update t1
join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
set t1.code = t2.code
```