# Select from a table and insert in another table with different order

Tags: mysql-python

With following query I retrieve some names from a table

```
query = "SELECT lastname FROM `firsttable` WHERE grp = 'C' AND av = '0' "

Caleb
Collins
Fiandre
Francis
Garmont
Gavelot
Maxima
Power
Zanzibar
Zavinsly
Saccult
Stancovich
Pedrocet
```

then these values must be inserted in another table with following query and this order

```
insert = "INSERT INTO `alldata` (name, year, month) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s') "%(lastname, yearold, monthold)

Caleb
Collins
Gavelot
Fiandre
Francis
Garmont
Maxima
Pedrocet
Power
Saccult
Stancovich
Zanzibar
Zavinsly
```

Comment: Use a `INSERT INTO` with a `SELECT` Example: `INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table1
WHERE condition;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INSERT with SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select)

Comment: Not exactly what I need, but I understand the principle and will work on that.